# how to make a right side JPanel display always

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have two Jpanels in a line, first JPanel used for showing a number of buttons and second showing left and right buttons.
I want to show the left,right buttons always(when change the screen size)

```
    public class TestJPanel {
public static void main(String... args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        panel.add(new JButton("Hello-" + i));
    }
    JPanel leftrightPanel=new JPanel();
    leftrightPanel.add(new Button("LEFT"));
    leftrightPanel.add(new Button("RIGHT"));
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    contentPane.add("West",panel);
    contentPane.add("East",leftrightPanel);
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,280);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Comment: It looks like you are adding panels to your contentPane panel as if the contentPane had a `BorderLayout` instead of a `BoxLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
contentPane.add(panel);
contentPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
contentPane.add(leftrightPanel);
```

This will separate the two panels to the left and right side of the screen with space in the middle. The space in the middle will change as the frame is resized.

```
contentPane.add("West",panel);
```

Never use hard coded magic strings like that. The API will provide a field for you to use. When you are using a BorderLayout properly, you would use:

```
contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working example on using the constraints and the proper add(...) method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.lang.String-java.awt.Component-), the `add` method you are using for `String, Component` is outdated. Regardless, the `String` parameter is just for the name of the component, and has no bearing on positioning. As it is now, the components are being placed exactly as you have prescribed: along the horizontal axis. If you wish to change that, there are a variety of things you can do, such as modifying the layout of the inner JPanels, using BorderLayout for the content panel and adding the inner panels to the appropriate location index, etc.

When you say that you want the rightmost panel and buttons visible at all times, you need to specify what the behavior should be of the left panel and its buttons. Should they occupy multiple lines? Should they be hidden? Should they shrink? If you clarify what exactly you want to happen, I could get you a more specific answer, but for now, the answer is simply that it is doing what you are telling it to.

An additional note, you used `JButtons` and `Buttons` inconsistently. Use one or the other, preferably `JButtons`, since every other component you used is Swing.